# Large time gap in debug log before ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG

Tags: managed-package, dml, debugging, performance

When viewing a debug log where the logging level was set to:

```
APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
```

I am seeing a large gap in time (~7 seconds) between my DML operation (followed by a heap allocate) and the entry into a manage package trigger. Does anyone know what is happening during these ~7 seconds? My understanding is that the managed package code is not running until the ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG statement, so does that mean that Salesforce is simply spending ~7 seconds waiting for the database?

Here is the log output from the operation in question:

```
12:07:22.840 (721566107)|DML_BEGIN|[542]|Op:Insert|Account|Rows:1
12:07:22.841 (721590807)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[EXTERNAL]|Bytes:12
12:07:29.159 (7064591521)|ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG|MyPkg
```

Comment: This is wildly speculative, but my best guess is that it's needing to recompile the managed apex for some reason.

Comment: I don't think this is the case because Salesforce made an update to the Apex runtime a while ago where Apex code now directly compiles to Java bytecode.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/12/apex-runtime-update-for-de-orgs.html

Comment: oh it absoluteley still does, but there are mechanisms for compiling and invalidating the resulting bytecode. Whenever there are material changes to the schema in an org for example it throws it away and re-compiles on the fly for the next request. Generally this happens at the start of the request, but I don't know the real meat of their implementation.